# Can Disney undo Lucas's changes to the original Star Wars films, now that they own the rights?

Tags: star-wars, disney, george-lucas

As we all know, Disney bought Lucasfilm in 2012 and with it, the rights to the Star Wars franchise. It is well publicised that George Lucas made changed to the original films that many fans were unhappy with, e.g. the question of who shot first in A New Hope and the "Noooo!" in Return of the Jedi.

My question is, now that Disney own Star Wars, could they revisit the earlier editions, re-edit them and undo the perceived damage that George Lucas did, thereby making their own Special Editions?

Comment: "Could"? MAAAAAYBE. Depends on what that 4B contract with Lucas entailed, and I strongly suspect that ain't getting shown to the public.

Comment: What's that infamous "Noooo!"?

Comment: Less infamous than a lot of other changes, eg Greedo shooting first

Comment: @DVK  The contract apparently included a clause that prohibits Lucas from doing anything that might hurt the property, as evidenced by his speedy backpedaling after he trashed the movie and called Disney "white slavers".  I doubt he would have abandoned ship so quickly and thoroughly unless Disney had something to threaten him with -  something like "Take that back or we will exercise our contractual rights to demand that you give us back the 3 billion dollars".

Comment: Could they alter the previous movies, by, say, undoing Lucas' changes?  Almost certainly.  Will they do so?  We're not that lucky.

Comment: @Wad Cheber - As far as I know he never actually trashed the movie in the Charlie Rose interview, or anywhere else. As for the "white slavers" comment, he had kind of an impish smile on his face when he said it, and laughed immediately afterwards--I think he was sort of amusing himself with the implications of the fact that he had just compared the movies to his "kids" and then Charlie Rose said "and you sold them". Of course it obviously tore at his heartstrings to sell the rights, but I don't think it's clear that he feels Disney has handled them badly or manipulated him into selling them.

Comment: @SS-3 - in the blu-ray edition of Jedi, Vader says "No" as the Emperor is zapping Luke and then says "NOOOO" as he grabs the emperor and tosses him over the railing, originally he was silent in that scene.

Comment: Re: Han shooting first, I found to my surprise and delight that the new canon novelization of "A New Hope" : "The Princess, The Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy" - http://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Hope-Princess-Scoundrel/dp/1484709128 - has Han shooting first.

Comment: @Hypnosifl It's tragic what George Lucas did to that scene. It's so much more powerful with a silent Vader. You "see" he is struggling with his conscience until he finally makes his mind up; the "noooooo" not only sounds ridiculous, it's also completely redundant!

Comment: Please be careful what you wish for. You shouldn't underestimate the creative might of Mickey Mouse.

Comment: It is certainly possible. [A fan did that already.](http://originaltrilogy.com/topic/Harmys-STAR-WARS-Despecialized-Edition-HD-V25-MKV-IS-OUT-NOW/id/12713)

Comment: The question is not if it's _physically_ possible, the question is if they have the legal rights to do so.

Comment: I *think* 20th Century Fox still has exclusive rights to distribute *Star Wars (1977)*, so Disney doesn’t actually own all the rights to the whole franchise. (I think I heard this somewhere on *The Incomparable* podcast, so I don’t have a reference.) Although I’m sure a deal could be made, much like Disney did with Sony regarding *Spider-Man*. Until then, as [@K. Gkinis](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58926/k-gkinis) says, it’s [Harmy’s Despecialized](https://www.facebook.com/despecialized/) all the way.

Comment: @SQB Nothing in the question mentions legal issues, but it says "now that Disney owns Star Wars"... it seems to me a question of practicality rather than legality.

Comment: I always have to laugh at "Han shot first" - that implies that someone shot *second*, but Greedo was *too dead* to shoot back!

Comment: What do you mean by "undo the changes"? Can you clarify if you just want to see a re-release of the original versions of the movies simply to view them, or if you want Disney to essentially revert the changes to canon that the special editions introduced?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Ooh! Good to know. I recently watched what I suppose must have been a blu-ray version, and was kind of weirded out by that scene. Thought it must be one of those things where a movie just doesn't seem as good as last time you saw it. Now I know why.

Comment: You know, CGI technology is awesome nowadays. If they can make Michael Douglas in Ant Man look like he did in the Streets of San Francisco then they can fix Star Wars even if they need to recreate the original characters and scenes with a computer.

Comment: I think the question is not if it's physically possible, the question is if they have the legal rights to do so and such.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Disney is buying 20th century fox.

Comment: @ibid: Disney’s buying everything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### George Lucas doesn't want them released

After it was announced that Disney was buying Fox (which would give Disney the *distribution* rights for the original trilogy), Pablo Hidalgo took to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/941435428200001536) to clarify that this had no effect on any plans for a release.

> **Pablo Hidalgo:** *Good morning! What's kept the original theatrical editions off of home video is the same thing that's always been doing that. It's not a studio thing.*
>
> **Well why leave us hanging here Captain Pablo?  WHAT is the grand reason that's keeping the Theatrical Versions off Home Video?  Please enlighten.**
>
> **Pablo Hidalgo:** *There is one notable person who doesn’t want them released.*

original answer below

> Filmmaker John Landis said they would during [an interview with Empire.](https://twitter.com/empiremagazine/status/645035349006159872)
>   
> >At a Q&A tonight John Landis dropped  that Disney are finally going to re-release the theatrical cuts of the original Star Wars trilogy.
>  Although I'm not sure how accurate this is, because these types of rumors have surfaced several times in the past.

Comment: It would be technically difficult to release the original trilogy unaltered. It is highly questionable whether or not the original film exists intact. The studio would have to go back to the original print, and do a new digital transfer in order to have a high enough quality to produce it. The people who produced the Harmy editions did a very good job fixing what they could. But, there are some scenes which they had to copy from the laserdisc versions, so they are not in HD. It would be great if they could fix all of the problems and release it commercially, but I am skeptical about it.

Comment: IMHO, the best version of STAR WARS was a "remastered" edition, which I think came out on VHS in the late-90s and, I think, is also the source for what is the LaserDisc version which super-fans MUST own.  In this version, much of the lighting is touched up, there is a little bit of color correction, each frame was cleaned up, etc. but nothing was added or taken away in regards to content.  It has been my long hope that whatever original content was archived from that original remastering could resurface on to Blu-Ray or whatever.  Certainly  LucasFilm handed these originals over to Disney.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson You might be mistaken. There was a release on DVD of the theatrical versions of all three movies with no changes and no fixes or enhancements. They probably still have the telecine and digital files created in order to master that DVD, and I would bet a lot that the special editions were edited on computer, not by cutting up a print of the original film. I'd be pretty surprised if there aren't many extant theatrical prints of all three movies.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The 2006 DVD version was a rip of the LaserDisc master, which was apparently the cheapest option and is limited to the resolution seen on the DVD. The Special Editions involved the original prints being permanently altered, since the negatives were in awful condition when they were found. It's not clear whether the changes involved any of the CGI additions though. More info here: http://originaltrilogy.com/

Comment: @JasonHutchinson I would be content, if there is no better option, with an officially produced SD copy on a modern medium, either DVD or Blu-Ray.  But I doubt very much that they can't do better.

Comment: As long as Disney might be altering the movies let me put in my bid for them to hire a good voice actor to completely overwrite young-adult Anakin's *whiny* voice!

Comment: How does Disney re-releasing the original theatrical cuts "undo Lucas's changes"? What it sounds like to me is a way for Disney to sell more copies of the 3 original movies, but doesn't alter canon in any way.

Comment: @Ellesedil, Lucas himself altered cannon when he changed the first shooter from Solo to Greedo. This has such a huge bearing on the morality and ethics of Han's character, which becomes very relevant towards his later actions especially in light of his story-arc in Episode_VII (no spoilers). Debates on what is Han Solo's "karma" depend on whether you are talking about the theatrical-release Han or the Lucas-edited Han.

Comment: @O.M.Y. - I'm not disagreeing with that. I just don't see how re-releasing the original cuts somehow "resets" the canon back to the original theatrical releases. But if that is Disney's intention, then someone at Disney needs to explicitly state that. Considering that, I'm not sure how this answer actually answers the question. It doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Ellesedil Imagine you're a parent with a kid who sees Han Solo as the perfect hero. Knowing that sooner or later they will hear about the WSF? controversy wouldn't you want to be able to show them the movie in its original form but from a clean release without using grainy copies from VHS or YouTube?

Comment: For that matter wouldn't you like to show your kids/grandkids the movie as you first saw it (assuming you are that old) just for nostalgia's sake?

Comment: @O.M.Y. - I'm not disagreeing with you. I interpreted this question that "undo the changes" means "undo the changes *in canon*", which may not be what the asker intended. So hopefully, he'll clarify.

Comment: Did this ever happen?

Comment: @Skooba - Nope.

Comment: How much say does this "notable person" have in whether they are released or not?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Judging by Pablo's tweet, enough to stop them from being released. I'm sorry for changing my answer from hopeful to depressive, but this seems to be the truth.